# vuejs 2 component design

Tags: vuejs2, custom-component

I created a vuejs table standalone component like:

```
<template>
    <header-with-many-specific-options/> *
    <generic-table/> *
</template>
<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {}
     }
  } 
etc.
</script>
```

* These aren't components but a representation of my messy template structure.

Now I want to turn my table into a reusable component and in order to do that I want to seperate the very specific header from the generic table, so I can swap in headers depending on what I need.
The header could have a table search, pagination or buttons for example.

Example:

```
<table-component>
    <user-table-header> <- can swap out
</table-component>
```

So yeah, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots). They're basically a placeholder for content within a component that can be specified within the tag for the component.

In your table component definition, you'd specify where you want to put the header content like this:

```
<template>
  <slot name="header"></slot>
  <generic-table></generic-table>
</template>
```

Then, wherever you use the component tag, add the `slot` attribute with the name `"header"` as the value to the element you want to go in the slot:

```
<table-component>
  <user-table-header slot="header"></user-table-header>
</table-component>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this considered a parent child relationship regarding interaction or is it 1 component?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The table component will be one component. If a component is passed into a slot (as in this case), that component won't have access to the table component vue instance

Comment: I mean how would my now seperate header interact with the table data?

Comment: "Interact" is a broad term. There are many different ways that one component can access the data and functionalities in another. Read up on [slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots), [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props), [events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#ad), and [$refs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)